# How to do validation in django serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 custom validation functions created using packages from PyPI, I want to inlcude them in my serializers.py in my django project before converting  it to JSON using rest. Problem is i dont know where or how to put the functions in such that the code will run through it. Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Jgt.png)(this is how im adding users right now, using the model's fields ive registered)
Here is my code:

```
/* serializers.py */ 
import re
import phonenumbers
from rest_framework import serializers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from validate_email import validate_email


class basicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    emailplus = serializers.EmailField()
    country = serializers.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_emailplus(self):
        email = self.validated_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email

/* views.py */ 
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import basic
from .serializers import basicSerializer


class basicList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        basic1 = basic.objects.all()
        serializer = basicSerializer(basic1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

As you can see I am not using models.py anymore and serializers.py as some sort of model with the given email and phone fields. In order for my function to work (which is not at the moment), it needs to use get() method from the entered data and do validate_email to know if the email exists. Please tell me what changes should be made, i do not know if the problem is with views.py which still uses models.py or if i should register the serializer as a model?

Answer (score 0):

To run your validations, you must call `serializer.is_valid()`, however, that requires data to be passed to the serializer not instances. The logic behind this is that drf validates data coming in not data already stored in your DB

**Correct logic**

Considerations

1. It looks like you are implementing a list view, but you are validating the email address, which is probably not what you intended to do in the first place. I am guess you want to validate email on create.
2. You can make use of drf's generic views and mixins such as `GenericViewSet`, `ListModelMixin`, and `ListModelMixin`
3. I think you have a type in `validate_emailplus` where you try to `get` the field `email` while the serializer declares it as `emailplus`
4. You seem not to be following PEP-8 (style guide for Python)

serializers.py

```py
import re
import phonenumbers
from rest_framework import serializers
from phonenumbers import carrier
from validate_email import validate_email


class BasicSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    emailplus = serializers.EmailField()
    country = serializers.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate_emailplus(self):
        email = self.validated_data.get("emailplus")
        if not validate_email(email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

class BasicViewSet(
    viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
):
    queryset = Basic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BasicSerializer
```

For a better understanding of how viewset and mixins work, I recommend checking [their implementation](http://cdrf.co)

**Validation in Admin site**

From the screenshot you added, it looks like you are trying to validate in the admin site, for that consider the below code:

models.py

```
class Basic(models.Model):
    ...

    def clean(self):
        if not validate_email(self.email, check_mx=True, verify=True):
            raise ValidationError("Invalid email")
```

This works because Django admin generates forms based on your models and then the forms call `full_clean()` on the model, which calls `clean()`

Comment: ive changed the code accordingly but theres an error which says cannot call is_valid as no data= keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.

Comment: @Jackson_Stake That's because you are trying to validate existing instances, not data, checkout my updated answer

Comment: actually I want to validate the email first using the function validate_emailplus and after that convert the data in json format to be displayed using apiview

Comment: @Jackson_Stake Why do you want to do that? Validation must be done before storing in the database to maintain database integrity, not validating when reading from database.

Comment: Thats what I meant actually, to validate the data before storing it in the database.

Comment: @Jackson_Stake then the code I provided in my answer should do that for the view. However, I am looking at the image you posted and it seems that you are talking about the admin site, which does not use your `APIView`

Comment: @Jackson_Stake to perform validation for the admin site, you can just add a `clean` function in your model, I'll update the answer now to perform validation for admin site.

Comment: I see what you mean but in the clean function, dont you need to get the email text from the emailfield using .get() and then do validate_email?

Comment: @Jackson_Stake, I am quite unclear on what you want to do. Is it: 1. You are creating instances of `Basic` in the admin site OR 2. You want to create a RESTful endpoint for creating instances of `Basic`?

Comment: option 1, and then once i know that a email is valid, convert the data into JSON data with REST. Apologies if Ive not answered your question as I am quite new to this

Comment: @Jackson_Stake what do you want to do with the valid email? In general, keep the validation seperate from the action you want to perform afterwads, so the `clean()` function will do the validation, then override the `save()` function in your model to perform the action you'd like to do, does that answer your question?